# make multiple parallel predictions on tensorflow model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, python-multiprocessing

I want to make multiple predictions.

I have trained a segmentation model (images and masks) . You can find the model [here](https://easyupload.io/5kjnj2).

The images have dimensions `(32,32,3)`. The masks `(32, 32)`.

What I am doing when I want to inference is:

Load the images array `(tiles)` with dim `(62500, 32, 32, 3)`. You can find it [here](https://easyupload.io/lrh8xf)

Create tensorflow dataset from this array.

and then predict on each image, like:

```
masks = [] 
for k, element in enumerate(the_image_array):
        the_img = np.asarray(np.expand_dims(element, 0))[-1, -1, :, :]
        pred = model.predict(the_img[np.newaxis, :, :, :])[0]
        mask = tf.where(pred > 0.5, 255, 0)
        masks.append(mask)
```

Now, I want to do these predictions in parallel.

So, I tried:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from itertools import chain
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool

os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'

multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn', force=True)


model = load_model('./model.h5',
                   custom_objects={"K": K})
     

def resize_and_rescale(image):
    image = tf.image.resize(image, 
                            (32, 32),
                            preserve_aspect_ratio=True)
    image /= 255.0
    return image
    
def prepare(ds):
    ds = ds.map(resize_and_rescale)
    return ds

def _apply_df(data):
    img = np.asarray(np.expand_dims(data, 0))[-1,-1, :, :]
    print(img.shape)
    pred = model.predict(img[np.newaxis,  :, :, :], verbose=2)[0]
    
    #pred = model.predict(data)[0]
    mask = tf.where(pred[:, :, -1] > 0.5, 255, 0)
    return mask

def apply_by_multiprocessing(data, workers):

    pool = Pool(processes=workers)   
    #result = pool.map(_apply_df, np.array_split(list(data.as_numpy_iterator()), workers))
    result = pool.map(_apply_df, data.batch(np.ceil(len(data) / workers)))
    pool.close()
    return list(result)


def after_prepare(data):
    tens_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data)
    tens_data = prepare(tens_data)
    return tens_data


def main():
    
    tiles = np.load('tiles.npy')
    print(len(tiles))
    print(tiles[0].shape)
    prep = after_prepare(tiles)
    print(len(prep))
    
    masks = apply_by_multiprocessing(prep, workers=4)
      
    masks_flatten = list(chain.from_iterable(masks))
    print(len(masks_flatten), masks_flatten[0].shape)  # 
    
    return masks_flatten
   
    
    
if __name__=="__main__":
    masks_flatten = main()
```

The `len(masks_flatten)` is 128 and the shape of an element is `(32,)`.

I would expect it to be `len=62500` and every element (mask) `(32, 32)`.

--- UPDATE ---

So, I want something like this:

```
def _apply_df(data):
    results = []
    for el in data:
        pred = model.predict(el[np.newaxis, :, :, :], verbose=2)[0]
        mask = tf.where(pred[:, :, -1] > 0.5, 255, 0)
        results.append(mask)
        
    return results
```

but without using the loop. Doing it in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is not incorrect, but even inside a single worker, it's better to let the TensorFlow/NumPy vectorization do its job instead of writing an explicit for loop:

```py
def _apply_df(data):
    pred = model.predict(data)
    mask = tf.where(pred.squeeze(axis=-1) > 0.5, 255, 0)
    return mask
```

This is the complete code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from itertools import chain
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool

os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"

multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn", force=True)


model = load_model("./model.h5", custom_objects={"K": K})


def resize_and_rescale(image):
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (32, 32), preserve_aspect_ratio=True)
    image /= 255.0
    return image


def prepare(ds):
    ds = ds.map(resize_and_rescale)
    return ds


def _apply_df(data):
    pred = model.predict(data)
    mask = tf.where(pred.squeeze(axis=-1) > 0.5, 255, 0)
    return mask


def apply_by_multiprocessing(data, workers):

    pool = Pool(processes=workers)
    # result = pool.map(_apply_df, np.array_split(list(data.as_numpy_iterator()), workers))
    result = pool.map(_apply_df, data.batch(np.ceil(len(data) / workers)))
    pool.close()
    return list(result)


def after_prepare(data):
    tens_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data)
    tens_data = prepare(tens_data)
    return tens_data


def main():

    tiles = np.load("tiles.npy")
    prep = after_prepare(tiles)
    masks = apply_by_multiprocessing(prep, workers=4)
    masks_flatten = list(chain.from_iterable(masks))

    print(len(masks_flatten), masks_flatten[0].shape)  # 62500 (32, 32)

    return masks_flatten


if __name__ == "__main__":
    masks_flatten = main()
```

Comment: But if I use this , it gives me length of flatten `128` instead of `62500` .. If I use the loop it works fine! And from 1 hour (without multiprocessing) it run it in 10 minutes!

Comment: Are you sure? It's different from your first function. It runs for 3 minuets on my system and gives the correct result length.

Comment: Yes, I am sure for the time and results. If I don't use the loop , I am getting flatten shape[0] 128 instead of 62500.. Very weird that you receive the correct shape without the loop!

Comment: I added the complete code I am running to my answer. There is nothing else I can think of at the moment.

Comment: So, you were right that it creates the right shape.. Now, the thing is that after receiving the `masks_flatten`, I am creating an image. If I use the `for-loop`, the image is fine. If I use your solution, the image is kind of messed. I can see some horizontal lines on it. So, I was wondering maybe when calling the `model.predict(data)` inside the `__apply_df`, it doesn't take in correct order the data? In contrast to when using the loop?

Comment: As I can see `pool.map` preserves the order. So, it must be something else.

Comment: So, I think the error is because you are using `pred.squeeze(axis=-1)` and I am using `pred[:, :, -1]`. I am just dropping the last dimension! Which is the channels .It is not 1. If I tty to use the same in your code, to use `mask = tf.where(pred[: ,:, -1] > 0.5, 255, 0)`, it give me shape `(32, 1)` instead of `(32, 32)`. If I just use  `pred.squeeze(axis=-1)` like you have , it gives me the messed image. If I use just ` tf.where(pred > 0.5, 255, 0)` , it give me blank image

Comment: Well then try `pred[:, :, :,-1]` in my answer to see what happens.

Comment: I just tried it! Still a black image (it takes only one value instead of 2)

Comment: Hi! It seems it works! It was another parameter combined with some PC hung that gave the wrong result! (upv)