# Keras multiprocessing model prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multiprocessing

I have a simple MNIST Keras model to make predictions and save the loss. I am running on a server with multiple CPUs, so I want to use multiprocessing for speedup.

I have successfully used multiprocessing with some basic functions, but for model prediction these processes never finish, while using the non-multiprocessing approach, they work fine.

I suspect that the issue might be with the model, as there is a single model it cannot be used in different parallel processes, so I loaded the model in each process, but it did not work.

My code is this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import tensorflow as tf

#make a prediction on a training sample
def predict(idx, return_dict):
  x = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(x_train[idx],axis=0))

  local_model=tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')
  y=local_model(x)
  print('this never gets printed')
  y_expanded=np.expand_dims(y_train[train_idx],axis=0)
  loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(y_expanded,y)
  return_dict[i]=loss

manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
return_dict = manager.dict()
jobs = []

for i in range(10):
    p = Process(target=predict, args=(i, return_dict))
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()
    
for proc in jobs:
    proc.join()

print(return_dict.values())
```

The print line in the `predict` function is never shown and the problem is with the model. Even without loading the model in the function and using a global one, the problem still persisted.

I followed this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70496446/parallelizing-keras-model-predict-using-multiprocessing) thread but it did not work. My questions are now these:

1. How to solve the model issue
2. Can I use the same `X_train` for all the processes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. First of all, Keras has issues with multiprocessing [1](https://lih-verma.medium.com/parallelizing-prediction-via-ml-dl-models-abf4a2032500), [2](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9964). Moreover, TensorFlow should always have one session. So, it must be imported only in the function, not anywhere else. And the model should be loaded from the disk in each function. This may be the source of improvement (moving the model to RAM, serializing the model as a file, and passing it to function).

Nevertheless, the below code *works*:

```
def predict(idx, return_dict):

  import tensorflow as tf

  x=tf.convert_to_tensor(x_train[idx])
  cce = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()

  local=tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')

  y=local(np.expand_dims(x,axis=0))
  y_expanded=np.expand_dims(y_train[train_idx],axis=0)
  loss=cce(y_expanded,y)
   
  return_dict[idx]=loss
```

The same `x_train` may be used.