# Multiprocessing a Tensorflow Model in Python

Tags: tensorflow, multiprocessing

I am trying to parallelize a simple tensorflow (lstm) model prediction in python

The dummy problem I'm facing is:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np


# Define the function to parallelize
def fun(model,input_model,particle):

    print(f'\nEvaluating particle {particle}\n')

    output = model.predict(input_model)
    return output

# Define the main
def main():
    # Load the model
    model = load_model('model_lstm.h5')
    model.summary()

    # Show it works
    dummy_prediction = model.predict(np.random.rand(1, 100, 14))

    # Prepare the input for multiprocessing
    tuple_aux = []
    for i in range(25):
        tuple_aux.append(tuple((model,np.random.rand(1,100,14),i)))

    # Implement the multiprocessing
    with mp.get_context("spawn").Pool(
            ) as pool:
        results = pool.starmap(fun,
                               tuple_aux)
    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Set the start method
    mp.set_start_method("spawn", force=True)

    # Call the main
    results = main()
```

For which the output before reaching the multiprocessing line is:

```
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 100, 14)]         0         
                                                                 
 lstm (LSTM)                 (None, 16)                1984      
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 200)               3400      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 5,384
Trainable params: 5,384
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 378ms/step
```

When the multiprocessing is reached, the code just hangs, after returning this error:

```
ValueError: Unknown metric function: 'function'. Please ensure you are using a `keras.utils.custom_object_scope` and that this object is included in the scope
```

I am not using any custom metric, which can be checked because the dummy prediction works, so I believe the trace of the model is being lost somehow. I also tried to directly load the model in the parallelized function, instead of giving it as an input, but still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow is already optimized and can use multiple CPU cores on its own. If you want parallelism, you could also use a batch for prediction. I'm not certain if you need to pass an array instead of a tuple, though.

```
model.predict(
    tuple_aux,  
    batch_size=len(tuple_aux),
    workers=10,  # number of workers
    use_multiprocessing=True
)
```

Here's a thread where multiprocessing is discussed: [Parallelizing Keras Model Predict Using Multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70496446/parallelizing-keras-model-predict-using-multiprocessing).
However, due to the way Python handles multi-core processing, this will always pose a challenge. I'm not entirely sure why you would want to use it in this specific manner."